# xampp and mysql all columns in table are lower case in php

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

If I print_r($object) I get:

```
Array ( [id] => 1 [ime] => rwe [letnica] => 0 [mesec] => 1 [datoteka] => [disciplineid] => 2 [rangtekmovanjaid] => 3 )
```

My DB columns are:

```
- disciplineId
- rangtekmovanjaId
```

I set `lower_case_table_names=0` in my.ini for mysql 5.0 part of xampp but is the same. What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_lower_case_table_names)

> You should NOT set this variable to 0
>   if you are running MySQL on a system
>   that has case-insensitive file names
>   (such as Windows or Mac OS X). If
>   you set this variable to 0 on such a
>   system and access MyISAM tablenames
>   using different lettercases, index
>   corruption may result. On Windows the
>   default value is 1. On Mac OS X, the
>   default value is 2.

[MySQL: Identifier Case Sensitivity](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html)

> In MySQL, databases correspond to
>   directories within the data directory.
>   Each table within a database
>   corresponds to at least one file
>   within the database directory (and
>   possibly more, depending on the
>   storage engine). Consequently, the
>   case sensitivity of the underlying
>   operating system plays a part in the
>   case sensitivity of database and table
>   names. This means database and table
>   names are not case sensitive in
>   Windows, and case sensitive in most
>   varieties of Unix. One notable
>   exception is Mac OS X, which is
>   Unix-based but uses a default file
>   system type (HFS+) that is not case
>   sensitive.

more

> By default, table aliases are case
>   sensitive on Unix, but not so on
>   Windows or Mac OS X.

That means, on Linux servers (Unix) table/column name "Test" **is not equal** with "test", "TEST", "tESt", etc. by default.

Comment: but if i move page from win to linux then everything stop working becouse column name is "rangtekmovanjaId" and in php i must use "rangtekmovanjaId" not "rangtekmovanjaid" like in windows. So how can i make in windows "rangtekmovanjaId" filed in mysql itentical to "rangtekmovanjaId" in php and not like "rangtekmovanjaid"

Comment: @senzacionale - No, it's not PHP... MySQL causes problems. Above, in first quotation you'll find `If you set this variable to 0 on such a system and access MyISAM tablenames using different lettercases, index corruption may result.`, I don't know any other solution then to rewrite all your table names to lowercase extension. I've faced similar problem year ago and since than, I'm using lowercase only for everything in PHP and MySQL.

Answer (score 10):

To fix this on XAMPP go to your my.ini file (e.g. inside C:\xampp\mysql\bin) and find the [mysqld] area.

Add to it the following line:

> lower_case_table_names=0

restart your apache & mysql

now your table names are case sensitive even on a windows system.